# MONGOENGINE How to get a document knowing only the value of one of the fields?

Tags: python, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I use flask-mongoengine for my app.
I have documents - Users.
I only need to get those with the name "Tim" (for example).
But I don’t know exactly what the name of the field is where the name is written.
It could be - "name", "username", "user_name" etc.

the request should look something like this:

```
users = User.objects.filter(**="Tim")
where ** - field, which i don't know
```

Maybe there are some other ways to do this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the advanced queries feature of MongoEngine ([link](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries))

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, Q


class Person(Document):
    firstname = StringField()
    lastname = StringField()

Person(firstname='Brian', lastname = 'Stella').save()
Person(firstname='Stella', lastname = 'Smith').save()

# Following query will found the 2 documents
Person.objects(Q(firstname__contains="Stella") | Q(lastname__contains="Stella")).count()
```